If Voyager is still an active NASA spacecraft, does it have a flight director? Is that a part time job?
I guess this is the first space mission that doesn't have any consoles or even a desk with  a little sign saying "Voyager Flight Control."
Does it at least have a P.O. box at NASA?

At the University of Iowa in 2014 I saw an old desktop computer that was connected to Voyager.

I presume there are any number of missions that no longer have a console or desk since they are defunct. Not quite sure exactly what you are asking here.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Partial answer
At least in 2017, Voyager Mission Control was a cubicle.

Suzanne Dodd, 56, the mission’s project manager, answered the door. She wore red-framed glasses over sharp blue eyes, and her fair hair was cut short. She escorted me past the vestibule to a common room ringed by office doors. Hanging over the cubicle partitions in the center was a shingle that read ‘‘Mission Control.’’
...
In the mission-control cubby, Medina, who is 68 and a grandfather of four, with a husky voice and a Tom Selleck mustache, rolled a chair over to two pairs of monitors labeled with construction-paper signs that read: ‘‘Voyager Mission Control Hardware, PLEASE DO NOT TOUCH.’’ He jiggled a mouse, and one of the screens woke to a stream of numbers and letters describing the health of Voyager 1.

Quotes from https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/03/magazine/the-loyal-engineers-steering-nasas-voyager-probes-across-the-universe.html (worth reading)
There's still a small team in 2024: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/pia26275-voyager-team-celebrates-engineering-data-return/

Note that Suzanne Dodd is now the Voyager Project manager. I suspect the team would call her should any key decision need to be made. I doubt there's a need for a Flight Director for a vehicle that is passive for 16+ hours a day that is run by a rather small crew.

There's a 2022 documentary 'It's Quieter in the Twilight' about the Voyager team.

If it truly is a single person doing mission control, why would that single person even need a flight director?

@DavidHammen it's not a single person. Both links show that there is a team. Agree about no need for a Flight.
